# gtk actions - warning MainWindow.Action hides inherited member Gtk.Widget.Action

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

I have warning *MainWindow.Action hides inherited member Gtk.Widget.Action. Use the "new" keyword if hiding was intended* in this part of automaticaly generated MainWindow.cs:

```
private global::Gtk.Action Action;
```

Also near this code I have more similar actions which I do not use (Action Action I do not use too).
This code is automaticaly generated, so how can I delete information about Action Action and other unused actions?
I tried to remove it on monodevelop subpage Actions (near Source code and Designer), but it is still here.
Every answer would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename "Action" to "Action0" in designer. However, a new created action will then named "Action", so all actions are to be renamed manually.